# How to trigger onCreate() when a new field is created in an existing Firestore document?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a new node in firebase realtime database when a field is created in an existing Firestore document.

I have been trying this:

```
exports.addUserCredentials = functions.firestore
    .document(`Users/{UserID}/{username}`)
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const newUserData = snapshot.data()
        const newUserUsername = newUserData
        const newUserUidDoc = context.params.UserID

        return admin.database().ref(`/userCredentials/${newUserUsername}`).set({"UID": newUserUidDoc})
    })
```

I have searched around the web I saw the path must be directed towards a document only and not a collection. BUT `username` in the path is a FIELD in the document.

I am getting this error while deploying and I have seen all similar questions but those didn't perfectly answered mine:

```
!  functions: failed to update function addUserCredentials
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
```

The reason is can't change my path to `Users/{UserID}` which will make my code run perfectly is the fields of document are not added at once.

Here is screenshot of my firestore structure:

[image]

The 4 fields of document are updated in 2 batches.

The EMAIL and timeCreated fields are added first and those create the document.
While on the other hand, phoneData and username are fields are CREATED [not updated] after 5 seconds of Email and timeCreated.

So if I use `onCreate()` on the path `Users/{UserID}`, it will return UNDEFINED to my realtime database as the username field is ABSENT at that instant.

Is there any way to apply `onCreate()` on a specific field of the document?

[*I am doing this to create a separate node which contains username and UID, this is to check if an username exists when a new user is trying to sign up*]
So if the node is created with value `undefined` it will be an issue.

It will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> The EMAIL and timeCreated fields are added first and those create the document. While on the other hand, phoneData and username are fields are CREATED [not updated] after 5 seconds of Email and timeCreated.

No matter what fields are adding once you created a document,it will be considered as an update operation against that document.As you mentioned in the question,there will be no field with field name called `username` with a document while you creating document.So it is not possible to get the value of `username` while you creating the document.

According to your explanation the field `username` will be only available with the `onUpdate` trigger.

So the code should be something like below

```
exports.addUserCredentials = functions.firestore
.document(`Users/{UserID}`)
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
    const beforeData = snapshot.before.data()
    const afterData = snapshot.after.data()


    if(!beforeData.username && afterData.username){
     return admin.database().ref(`/userCredentials/${newUserUsername}`).set({"UID": newUserUidDoc})
    }

})
```

Comment: Why 4 invocations..?

Comment: It will cost atleast 2. Because these fields are being added one by one. If email is added, then username. These will invoke 2 times

Comment: `email` and `timecreated` are added while creating the document.? the `username` will be added once you created the document .Right?So it will cost only one function invocation

Comment: There won't be any document at first. `email` and `timeCreated` will be added using `.set()` which will create the document. Document name is the user UID. Then after 5 seconds (time varies). `username` and `phoneData` will be added using `set()` from my Android App using `SetOptions.merge()` so that it won't delete the email n time created

Comment: `Setoption.merge()` will considerd as an update by firestore if the document already exist,no matter what field you are adding,no matter whether the field is already existing or not

Comment: Moving this to a discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212475/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-pepe).